# Fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 - how can I move home directory to another hard drive?

Tags: home-directory, 17.10

I am looking to move my Home directory to another hard drive (I have an SSD and a larger spinning drive).  I have looked at instructions online, I'm not finding any that work though.  Maybe they are a bit outdated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this comprehensive help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving If it does not work, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/968851/edit) your questions and add where you got stuck and copy and paste the exact errors you got.

Answer (score 1):

Use gparted or another partitioning tool to create the partition you want to use for `/home`. Record the UUID of the new partition.

Copy all you files from `/home` to the new partition (this includes the folder `/user`). Don't forget the hidden folders.

Edit `/etc/fstab` and add the following lines:

```
# /home partition
UUID=<uuid recorded earlier> /home   ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Next, reboot your system

After confirming that your new `/home` partition is working correctly, you can delete the contents of the old home folder since only the folder `/home` is necessary for the mount point.

Note: if you formated with something other that ext4, change it to match the file system used.